# what makes you think money isn't a part of the economy?

Tags: discussion

I created a question a few minutes ago about how J.P. Morgan funded the American economy, but someone says: it's `off-topic`. The reason this question was asked here is because it's says: [`Money`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Money) at the end, `Personal Finance & Money`, Please, what makes you think money isn't a part of the economy, and what didn't allow you to add `Economy` tag?

Answer (score 5):

For those of us who have seen this discussion before, a tangential meta-meta comment: https://youtu.be/jEIz0SM7dkA

For those when haven't:

https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

[Should we remove the "& Money" part from the site name and logo, to prevent repeated confusion about what is on-topic?](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1949/should-we-remove-the-money-part-from-the-site-name-and-logo-to-prevent-repe)

@AdamuDeeAzare: Unfortunately, despite the name, the intended reading is PERSONAL (FINANCE & MONEY), and policy explicitly says economics is off topic. Some of us have been trying for years to persuade SE to make the name and banner match the declared scope of this stack, pointing to misunderstandings such as yours, but with no success. Not your fault, but it is the wrong place to ask.

The fact that it looked like a "do my homework assignment for me" question didn't help. Nor did the fact that it's too broadly scoped for a direct answer in less than essay length.

I believe there is a separate economics Stack, but the scope of this question may be too vague for them too.

Comment: Should we get rid of the Economy tag, at least? (Maybe replace it with a tag for Premium or Diesel?)