# Are questions about student society bookkeeping on-topic here?

Tags: support, allowed-topics

I'm the treasurer for a university student-run society. The society has between 500-1000 members and receives $10,000-20,000/year in dues from the membership. We are audited three times per year by the university's Student Union. The auditors are students who often don't have much experience in managing finances, and have been unable to answer many of my questions. I have some specific questions about bookkeeping for this sort of society, and I wanted to determine if I can ask them here.

After reading the [on-topic help page](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) I can see that bookkeeping for sole proprietorships is on-topic, but I don't think a student-run society really fits that description. On the other hand, by business standards our financial needs are quite simple and are more similar to personal finance than business finance.

Can I ask questions about bookkeeping for university student-run society on this site?

Comment: After searching more meta questions I may have found the answer, but I'd like to see someone from the community weigh in.

Comment: You answered your own question, fairly accurately, I'd say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions about accounting and bookkeeping for a business and organization are off-topic, but questions about how someone's personal finances relate to their business are on-topic. Since the student society does not affect personal finances, and the type of question suggested is more about how to run the society, it is not on-topic.

This was covered by a combination of [this answer](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2213/55552) about the appropriateness of accounting questions and [this answer](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16/55552) about the appropriateness of small-business questions.